# Can't log in due to Steam Guard and an inactive email account, what now?

Tags: steam

I am unable to log into my Steam account as I do not have access to my email account for the Steam Guard verification process.

I have raised a ticket but have not received a reply from Steam Support yet, and it has been over two days so far.

I am really desperate because I just put $20 on there and that's really rare for me. There is no way to activate my email account which the verification code has been sent.

What can I do to resolve this issue and regain access to my Steam account?

Comment: The only way you're going to get your account back is through Steam Support, or through your email account. There's literally nothing we can do to help. I hope you get your account back, though!

Comment: umm.. thanks, I am not sure what happened to the title of the this heading but the original was that I cant login to steam cause I need the verification code but its been sent to an inactive account.... thanks so much for replying.. that was sorta fast and unexpected (under 5 min)

Comment: @kotekzot edited the title to be more informative to other users. (See the "edited X mins ago"-message.) The verification code you speak of is from Steam Guard. It's an active site so there's usually some sort of response within minutes. You might want to read some of the help articles to better understand the site. :)

Comment: oh... first time so on this site cause I was asking a question on google and this came up, it didn't answer my question so I typed on this instead. thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 15):

If you're unable to access the email address attached to your Steam account, you will need to raise a ticket via [Steam Support - Regaining access to your lost Steam Account and resetting your account credentials](https://support.steampowered.com/newticket.php).

While waiting your support ticket, choose ***STEAM*** as the product and **Account Questions** and **Steam Guard/Email Verification** as the categories.

Steam are going to ask for confirmation of who you are (Steam call this "Proof of Purchase"), this can normally be provided in the following forms. Please note: **do not reply to this answer with any of the following information, this needs to be sent to Steam Support *only***;

- If retail software is registered to the account, attach a digital photo or scan of the CD Key registered to the account. Write your Support Ticket Number on the quick reference card or CD Key sticker below the code in permanent ink.

  [image]

  [image]

  [image]
- If a game was purchased through Steam with a credit card, please provide the following:

  - The Card Type (Visa, MasterCard, Discover, American Express)
  - Full Name on the Card
  - The last four digits of the credit card number - Do not provide the full credit card number
- If a game was purchased through Steam using a PayPal account, please provide:

  - The Billing Name on the PayPal Account
  - The full Billing Address on the PayPal Account
  - The PayPal PayerID
  - The Invoice ID and the Transaction ID

If any other payment method was used you'll need to explain this in the support ticket.