# Steam Locked Me Out- Please help!

Tags: steam

I tried to log into Steam and it was having trouble connecting. I restarted my PC, thinking it was a connection issue (I get them all the time, no big deal), but restarting it only seemed to make it worse.

When I put in my password, it said "Login to Steam failed. Either the specific account does not exist, or the password was wrong. Please check your account name and password and try again." At this point I thought I just typed my password wrong, yet several tries later, that black and white message of death haunted me yet again.

Getting a bit agitated, I tried to reset my password. I waited over 24 hours, and I never got the e-mail. I tried to reset my password where I could use my e-mail directly, yet the e-mail I got wasn't for my account, just a ghost one :P.

Finally, I decided to contact Steam support. I got almost instant feedback, but they only gave me tips on things I already tried! I have about $700 worth of games and over 1,000 hours, and I really do not want to start over. Please help.

PS: I already tried running Steam in TCP mode, deleting clientregistry.blob, etc. (It may be a possibility, but I could have been hacked. I want to try everything else before accepting the fact I may or may not have been hacked)

Comment: Are you able to log into steamcommunity.com?

Comment: I tried to, but I got the same result as trying to log in on the Steam Client :/

Answer (score 3):

Steam doesn't "lock you out" - the error messages you're getting sound like you're entering the wrong username or password, since you're not even getting as far as the Steam Guard request.

If you don't know your username or password you *will* need your email address in order to reset it using the options in the Steam client or Steam website. The email address you've entered so far is obviously for another account, since you got a password reset for said other account when you used it.

Failing that, you're going to have to contact Steam support and hope they're able to help you, and [we've already got the rest of that process covered in another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/147181/52800).

Comment: 3 days ago, I tried to login into steam and got the same error. I even tried to reset the password, which worked fine, but it still gave me the same error message (invalid username/password), although i was able to login into the website. The issues was solved after a few hours, and a good buddy of mine had the same problem last friday. So steam definitely has some issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover your Steam account by contacting their support and following their instructions.  Somewhere along the line you will have to provide the last couple digits of the credit card used to make purchases.  DON'T just randomly give them your number.  Ask them what to do about your account, and wait for further instructions.

I have had to recover my account via similar manner and have changed my Steam account to use a unique password that I don't use anywhere else.