# What can I do because of 'Duplicate Product Code' on Steam?

Tags: steam

I've just created a new steam account and wanted to activate Half-Live there. Then I got this error message:

[image]

When I click on 'Retrieve Account', nothing happens. I am quite sure that I have already activated this many years ago on another account, but I don't remember which account (and which email-address) I used.

When I click on '[See the Steam support site for more information](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=276)' it seems not to contain helpful information.

I have the original CD and even the receipt.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 10):

Fortunately, because you have the receipt for the game you should be able to basically [follow this process with Valve/Steam Support](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/147181/52800) but from a stand point of "I once had this account but don't remember what it was and can prove this game is mine" instead of "I've no longer got this email address". The rest of the process should be the same.

In the instance that you have no proof of purchase for that game, and nothing else linking you to the account, there would be nothing you could do to redeem the game/product a second time.

Comment: A brief warning. I had this exact same situation (with the exact same game, in fact) and was able to prove to Valve that I owned the product. However, to my annoyance rather than transferring the product to my new account, they reset the email on my old account to be the same as on my current one. So I can now play the game if I want, but I have to re-log in especially to do it.

Comment: I had to reset a password this weekend and there was an option to retrieve your account name by a product key. 
@Matt Thrower activate Familiy Sharing with your old account; this should allow you to play whenever you want since your old account's steam library probably isn't used.