# Some Steam Troubles

Tags: steam

I have an old Steam account with a really old email address. Steam wants to send me an account verification code due to my PC being replaced and upgraded since I created the account. My PC changes have also made my old Outlook email inaccessible. Outlook needs to know the emails I sent and what content they contained, but I never sent any emails via that email address. Thus, I cannot recover my old account. I tried clicking the Settings option on my Steam browser, but nothing happened. Is there *any* possible way I could access my old Steam account and regain access to the games I have?

Comment: Probably the best we can help is: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147169/cant-log-in-due-to-steam-guard-and-an-inactive-email-account-what-now. Your question doesn't mention Steam Guard, but the solution is the same: contact Valve. We can't help.

Comment: @Frank it does mention steam guard. "Steam wants to send me an account verification code"

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you answer lies in contacting directly the company that owns your old e-mail address. Since you use Outlook I am going to guess Microsoft. They have a number you can call and speak with someone while on the phone with them you may be able to recover your e-mail account. Once your e-mail account is recovered you should have no trouble in recovering your steam account. If you cannot find the number which I am currently having the trouble you can use the following.

Microsoft Contact Us link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/